# How to get "name" attribute of html tag using php getStr?

Tags: php, html, getstring

I'm trying to find a way to get the content of this HTML attribute "name", using PHP getStr, I can't get it to work anyhow, I have already searched, but I couldn't find find something that may help me.

```
<input id="9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b.subject" maxlength="50" name="9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b:subject" value="" tabindex="1" class="subject required field" type="text"/>
```

I want to get this value into a string:

> 9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b:subject

I can get the value of a tag like this one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="1442814179635.Oz1LxjnxVCMMJ0QpV0wGLx4roEA="/>
```

With this code:

```
getStr($b,'name="message" value="','"');
```

But I can't find a way to get the attribute name of the first one?

Comment: You should save that value in your value attribute not in name attribute.

Comment: @Shivam, I didn't get what you mean, I want the value inside the "name=" I want this value"

Comment: don't use regex to parse html, use a dedicated library

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions in PHP. This code should be helpful:

```
<?php

$str  = '<input type="hidden" name="message" value="1442814179635.Oz1LxjnxVCMMJ0QpV0wGLx4roEA="/>';

//forward slashes are the start and end delimeters
//third parameter is the array we want to fill with matches
if (preg_match('/name="([^"]+)"/', $str, $m)) {
    print $m[1];   
} else {
   //preg_match returns the number of matches found, 
   //so if here didn't match pattern
}
```

Output:

```
message
```

Comment: you shouldnt EVER parse html with regex read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2847024)

Comment: Only the sith deal in absolutes

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP [DOMElement::getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method. It's all in the manual

Here you go:

```
<?php
$html = '<input id="9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b.subject" maxlength="50" name="9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b:subject" value="" tabindex="1" class="subject required field" type="text"/>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("input");
foreach($elements as $element){
   echo $element->getAttribute('name');
}
?>
```

Comment: this would be the right answer if it had more detail in it.

Comment: @DevDonkey Alright, alright, I've added the complete answer, even though people should do a little bit of research on their own

Comment: if youre going to answer, answer properly. if you dont think a question should be answered because its a bad question, then dont.

Comment: @DevDonkey sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code will do what you want:

```
    <?php

        $b = '<input id="9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b.subject" maxlength="50" name="9d6e793e-eed2-4095-860a-41ca7f89396b:subject" value="" tabindex="1" class="subject required field" type="text"/>';

        echo "\$b = $b\n";

        $rest = substr(strstr($b,'name="'),6);

        echo "\$rest = $rest\n";

        $name = strstr($rest,'"',true);

        echo "\$name = $name\n";

    ?>
```